# Put a 2-d array in another 2-d array java

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble figuring out how to put one 2-D array into another one.

```
public class MazeAnalyze{
public static void main(String[]args){
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in); 
  String str = ""; 
  System.out.println("Enter dimensions"); 
  int n = kbd.nextInt(); 
  char [][] mazeValue = new char[n][n];
  char[][] newMaze = new char[n+2][n+2]; 
  String [] input= new String [n]; 
  int [][] totalOpen = new int [n][n];
  char X= 88;
  System.out.println("Enter the maze"); 
  for(int i =0; i <input.length; i++){ 
   input[i] = kbd.next().toUpperCase();  
  }
  for(int x=0; x< input.length;x++){
  mazeValue[x]= input[x].toCharArray(); 
  }
  System.out.println("The maze array contains:"); 
  for(int i=0; i<mazeValue.length; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<mazeValue[i].length;j++){
     System.out.print(mazeValue[i][j]);
  }//end of second loop 
  System.out.println(); 
  }//end of first loop  
System.out.println("The maze with the Xs are"); 
for(int i=0; i<newMaze.length; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<newMaze[i].length;j++){
     newMaze[i][j]= 'X';   
  }//end of second loop 
 }//end of first loop
for(int i=0; i<newMaze.length; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<newMaze[i].length;j++){
      System.out.print(newMaze[i][j]);
  }
System.out.println(); 
}
for(int x=0; x<n-2; x++){
    for(int i=0; i<mazeValue.length; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<mazeValue[i].length;j++){
        newMaze[i+1][j+1]= mazeValue[i][j]; 
      }
    }
  }//end of main for loop
```

This is my output:

Enter dimensions
3
Enter the maze

xox

xoo

ooo

The maze array contains:

XOX

XOO

OOO

The maze with the Xs are

XXXXX

XXXXX

XXXXX

XXXXX

XXXXX

The maze with the border is

XOX

XOO

OOO

What I want is:

My maze array surrounded by X's like a border. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way in your case seems to be using string concat and add `"X"` and the beginning and end of each line, and in addition add 2 lines to `input` - one at the start and one at the end, all containing only "XXX...X".

Note: It might be easier to use an `ArrayList<String>` or `LinkedList<String>` for `input` rather than `String[]` - adding elements at the start and end would be easier.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do it using loops?